# subversion C API example

Tags: svn

I need to create a simple svn client application which will list the directories for given url. I have included the svn header files and library files in the project.

How can i get the list for given url by using API ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with SVN, but from a quick look at the API it seems that what you're looking for is one of the client list functions declared in svn_client.h, for example [this one](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/latest/group__List.html#gad8f85e87bd1c8adaa0ad31eb1913c3c9).